# Register COM/dll on Azure

Tags: azure, com, azure-storage

i have one online portal which is having online payment facility , somehow my azure lost all settings and my payment gateway not working. i have used one dll for payment gateway so i think i need to register that on Azure please help me what should be done ?

Comment: How did you register the DLL when you 1st setup your application to run in Windows Azure? Can't you repeat the same steps again?

Answer (score 0):

Azure uses VMs with more or less usual Windows Server installations. You can register a COM dll there no problem from under any process having sufficient privileges.

That's such a usual procedure that I don't even know what to add - perhaps you should provide more details on where you've got stuck.

Comment: Useful answer but needs more info on how to go about running a process on Azure.

Comment: @StephenPrice: The same way as you would on Windows - using `Process` class in C# code or using appropriate statements in batch files and scripts.